# sliding in a dropdown inside a div with overflow hidden

Tags: css, animation, overflow, hidden, sliding

I'm creating a sliding animation for a dropdown inside a div, but the "overflow:hidden" of this div is preventing to show the dropdown list when we click on the dropdown to open it.

I'm aware that this "overflow:hidden" lets me slide the dropdown off without adding extra width to the page... so the question: how can I keep both the sliding animation and be able to show the dropdown menu when it's open?

Comment: you have to take dropdown outside the element with overflow: hidden, or resign with using overflow: hidden;

Comment: can you add the html/css code please? the usual method is to animate `max-height` instead of `height`